# TFS 2017 on-premise can't install Marketplace extensions in connected mode

Tags: tfs, marketplace

My TFS 2017 Update 2 on-premise is according to the Marketplace  (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) running in Connected Mode. Whatever extension I try to install in this mode results in the error message:

> Something's gone wrong
>
> We've encountered an error while downloading the extension. Please try
>   again later.

If I try to install the same extension in my VSTS account it works fine.

If I disconnect my TFS on-premise from the Marketplace the "Install" button changes to "Get it free" and I can get to the download page for the extension and get the extension that way.

The error message gives no clue as to where I should start searching for the root case. Is the Marketplace having issues or is the error on my end? Do I need to open a firewall port? Something else?

I have tried this on two separate connected TFS 2017 Update 2 on-premise installations and get the same behaviour. I have TFS Administrator (Console Admin) rights on both.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the permissions first to make sure you have the correct permissions to install the extensions:

> **What do I need to install extensions?**
>
> [Project collection administrators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions?view=tfs-2018&tabs=new-nav) with [Edit collection-level
>   information permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=tfs-2018#collection) can install extensions. If you don't have
>   permissions, you can request extensions instead.

Well, I tested on TFS 2017 Update3 (no update2 on my side) while connected to TFS and everything works as expected, cannot reproduce the issue...

However that might be an temporary network issue, so just as the error message said you can try that again later... If the issue persist, then as a workaround you can download the extension from Marketplace and [upload to TFS to install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=tfs-2018#upload-to-team-foundation-server).
You can also try upgrading to TFS 2017 Update 3, it should work for you.

Refer to [Install extensions for Team Foundation Server (TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=tfs-2018) for details.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have the needed permissions and yes, I know of the workaround. I believe I mentioned both in my original post. I have installed most of our extensions so that is not the issue. Asking me to install Update 3 to see if that helps, seems like a tall order and somewhat of a guess. We are looking into Update 3 but that is beside the point. Is there a log file or something I can trace to try to find the root cause?

Comment: @MichaelHarmsen Can you reproduce this issue with other accounts? Are there any policies/rules firewall settings etc which may block the connection to marketplace? Just try clean the caches on your client machine then try it again. For logs, I can think of is that you can try check the Activity by navigating to `http://server:8080/tfs/_oi/_diagnostics/activityLog` or check system event log...

Comment: Yes, we can reproduce this across different accounts, on different pc's and using different browsers (IE and Chrome). Nothing shows up in the Activity log or the event logs. But we do seem to have an issue with a policy. If I browse the Marketplace from the actual server (and not my pc) and try to sign in I am told that a policy is blocking access to login.microsoftonline.com. I'll figure out what to do on our side but it seems misleading that when browsing from my pc the Marketplace states that I am logged in and running in Connected Mode.

Comment: @MichaelHarmsen So, the problem is caused by the policy, you need to figure it out first, you can ask your IT administrator to assist with this...

Comment: Sure, the blocking policy is at my end so I'll deal with that. Then you can fix the misleading status on the Marketplace that states I'm running in Connected Mode when I'm not, right? :)