# How do I get TFS on-premise Delivery Plans back after I removed them?

Tags: tfs

I am running TFS 2017 Update 2 on-premise. I had Delivery Plans installed and working. During a test I removed Delivery Plans by browsing to http://#TFSURL#/tfs/_gallery/manage where I selected Remove in the menu like this:

[image: Remove Delivery Plans]

Now I want to install Delivery Plans again, but where do I find them?

The extension does not show up in the server gallery at http://#TFSURL#/tfs/_gallery and I cannot download the version on the Marketplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported according to Buck Hodges (@tfsbuck on Twitter). The only way is to reinstall TFS. Read Buck's answer here: https://twitter.com/DonovanBrown/status/1059389630745886721

Answer (score 0):

As you have removed the `Delivery Plans` extension from local extensions, so it won't show up in the server gallery any more at `http://#TFSURL#/tfs/_gallery`.

To install it again you need to in `connected mode`(see [Install extensions while connected to TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=tfs-2018#install-extensions-while-connected-to-tfs)):

1. From your TFS home page (`https://{server}:8080/tfs/`), go to the
   project collection where you want to install the extension.
2. From your project collection, go to the Visual Studio Marketplace (Hover mouse on the `bag icon` in the top right corner --> `Browse Marketplace`).
3. TFS is connected to the Marketplace, then you can find the `Delivery Plans` extension and install it again.

[image]

Comment: Nope, I can't do that. First of all the Marketplace version is two major versions ahead of the local version I had (15.117.x vs 17.142.x) so I would not be getting the same version I had, which I would expect. Secondly I can't install extensions while in connected mode as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762033/tfs-2017-on-premise-cant-install-marketplace-extensions-in-connected-mode. If I disconnect and try to install Delivery Plans I can only install it on an Azure account and not on-premise. There should be an extension file locally on my system, right?

Comment: Yes, it's the pre-installed extensions (first-party), it exists once you have configured the on-premise TFS. However you have removed it now, it's not there any more. Generally in disconnected mode you have to upload the extension package (`*.vsix` file) to install the extension again. But for the extension `Delivery Plans` we cannot download the package (`*.vsix` file)...The only way we can do is installing the extension with connected mode. Besides, I want to know why you have to get the same version with the one you have removed. The new version is also apply to TFS 2017.2

Comment: I have removed the extension from my system, sure. I didn't expect that I also removed the source .vsix file so I can't upload and install the extension again. We want to have control over the software versions that we deploy in our environments. So if we tear apart some installation we need to be able to re-create the exact same installation with the exact same software versions. I can't do that in this case but will probably have to re-install TFS to get Delivery Plans back. Other extensions can be downloaded and backed up, but this can't. Do you see a problem here?

Comment: @MichaelHarmsen Well, you can create a user voice on [this site](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services)  to suggest the feature. In my opinion generally we will use the latest version, even for other extensions, if you never backed up the previous versions, then you will always get the latest version. In other words once you removed the old version and no backups, then you can only get the latest version.

Comment: I work in a highly regulated industry so I am not in a position to just use the latest version and I will most likely not be able to run TFS in Connected Mode. I can't backup the Delivery Plans extension from 2017 Update 2 as I don't know where the .vsix file is. Creating a UserVoice for this issue will probably not get much support - but I can consider it. I tried a couple of other things in a sandbox: repair Update 2, remove and install Update 2, create a new Collection  - none of those helped. Update 3 gave me Delivery Plans back so I'll do that and hope nobody removes the extension again.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install the Delivery Plans extension back after it is removed from the local gallery - provided the corresponding vsix file is available.

The name of the vsix file for Delivery Plans extension is Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Extension.Work.Plans.Web and it can be found in "C:\Program Files\Azure DevOps Server 2019\Tools\Deploy\TfsServicingFiles\Extensions" assuming that Azure DevOps server is installed in C directory.
Once the file is available upload it to the local gallery, from where it can be installed back and made available to the collection.

This worked for me. I am using Azure DevOps 2019 Update 1.1.

Also please check the extension version before installing. Version compatibility could cause issues to the existing setup.